# Vandermonde Determinant $V = V_n(x_1, . . . , x_n)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $W$ be the matrix obtained from $V = V_n(x_1, . . . , x_n)$ by replacing
the last column $(x_1^{n−1},\ldots,x_n^{n−1})^T$ with $(x_1^n,\ldots, x_n^n)^T$. Show directly that $\det W = (x_1 + · · · + x_n)\det V$.

I proceed with the proof by induction. There is nothing to
show if $n = 1$ or $n=2$. I need help with the cases when  $n\ge 3$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $V'=V_{n+1}(x_1,\cdots,x_n,t)$
$$\det V'=\prod_{k=1}^n(t-x_k)\prod\limits_{1\leqslant i<j\leqslant n}(x_j-x_i)=(\det V)\prod_{k=1}^n(t-x_k)$$
However, if you expand the last row of $V'$, you will find that the coefficient of $t^{n-1}$ is $-W$, so $W=(\det V)\sum\limits_{k=1}^nx_k$

Comment: [+1] Well done.